# Spring-boot how to use autowired class properties in called method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired, spring-test

I have the following class in my spring-boot application

```
public class ClassA {

    @Autowired
    PropertiesClass propertiesClass;

    public Integer getMeSomeValue(Integer someParameter) {
        // uses some methods of propertiesClass
    } 
}
```

Here, propertiesClass actually contains methods which reads property values from application.properties file. I want to unit test the getMeSomeValue method. My unit test class is given below

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(MyApplication.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
public class ClassATest {

    @Test
    public void testGetMeSomeValue() {
        ClassA classA = new ClassA();
        Assert.assertSame("Received expected response", classA.getMeSomeValue(6025), 2345);
    }
}
```

When I run the unit test, I get null pointer exception at the point where methods of propertiesClass are invoked inside getMeSomeValue method. Is there any way in Spring-boot to make the @Autowired work?

Comment: When you manually instantiate `ClassA` via `new`, the spring IoC container (app context) has no opportunity to inject your `PropertiesClass` bean. Consider making a `ClassA` bean in your test configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
ClassA classA = new ClassA();
```

Do this...

```
@Autowired
ClassA classA;
```

So that classA bean will be available within **Spring Container.**

Answer (score 1):

Calling the new constructor on ClassA will not inject your wired PropertiesClass as it is not 'made' by Spring.

Instead do

```
@Autowired
ClassA classA;
```

Make sure that the beans are called in MyApplication.class, this will make them available in the context as you are not using component scanning.